# Flutter get all images from gallery no manually select with image_picker

Tags: flutter

So I want to get all images from phone gallery in Flutter.Because I want to show this images to my DragableScrollabel Wiget.I means in viber application.If you click viber image icon and then you will see all images from gallery.Firstly I use image_picker , but It is manually pick use pickMulti().But I don't want to pick manually.I want to get all gallery images list.Please help me!

I tried various way.But all is not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.